# Oracle : SQL for Grouping sublevels

Tags: sql, oracle

I have this table, how can I query this table to have sample output below where the passed parameters are Item_Name and Spec_Name Thank you.

```
Item_Name   Item_Value     Spec_Name   Spec_Value
---------   ----------     ---------   ----------
Circle      Zed Circle     Diameter    180
Circle      Charlo Circle  Diameter    330
Square      Ash Square     Side        120
```

Sample output for Item_Name=Circle and Spec_Name = Diameter:

```
 Circle             Zed Circle - Diameter
 -------------     ---------------------
 Zed Circle         180
 Charlo Circle      330
```

I've try using MAX() function but it only give me 330. :(

Here is the whole query :

```
   SELECT CASE
     WHEN (ITEM_NAME = 'Circle') THEN
      MAX(ITEM_VALUE)
   END AS "Circle",
   CASE
     WHEN (ITEM_NAME = 'Circle' AND SPEC_NAME = 'Diameter') THEN
      MAX(SPEC_VALUE)
   END AS "Circle - Diameter"
  from TBL_SHAPES
```

Edited the user has tried this, mention in comments.

```
CASE WHEN (ITEM_NAME = 'Circle' AND SPEC_NAME= 'Diameter') 
THEN MAX(SPEC_VALUE) END
```

thanks ahead.

Comment: please explain what you are trying to do as what you're doing now will require a simple: `select * from table where  Item_Name='Circle' and Spec_Name = 'Diameter'`

Comment: Sorry made a mistake in the desire output. I tried : CASE WHEN (ITEM_NAME = 'Circle' AND SPEC_NAME= 'Diameter') THEN
    MAX(SPEC_VALUE)
END

Comment: Please post in SQL statement that you have used. also let know the expected output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried using `WHERE` ?

```
SELECT item_value AS Circle, spec_value AS Diameter
FROM tbl_shapes
WHERE item_name = 'Circle' AND spec_name = 'Diameter'
ORDER BY spec_value
```